# Docusign connect event Notification Rest Api

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am using docusign rest api v2.1 using python. During envelope creation process, we will send our rest API URL HTTPS to receive the notifications but we are not receiving notifications.

I had also configure Docusign Connect custom configuration but still i am unable to receive notifications.

when i check the failed connect notification it give a error

https://someurl.com/docusign/callback :: Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

You can see my Docusing Connect Configuration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpCNk.png)

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm, this seems too obvious, so I didn't want to reply, but do you need to replace `https://someurl.com/docusign/callback` with your own's app URL? Where do you host your server? is it accessible over the internet? no firewall? proxy? etc.
I would suggest you consider hosting on a cloud like AWS or Azure and see it work there first. We have examples for this if you neeed.

Comment: someurl.com is a sample url. my app is hosted over the internet and it can access from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

These days, I recommend using an intermediate system for handling webhook notifications. It is more reliable, more secure, and no changes to your firewall configuration are needed!

And the cost is free (like free beer). Check out my [blog post series](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4/), complete with example code.